# How do I store a block of html (with embeded PHP) in a PHP variable?

Tags: php, html

I am new to wordpress themes and PHP.  (I don't believe this is specific to WP) I would like to know the best way to store a block of HTML (with embeded PHP code) in a PHP variable.

```
<?php
function rfttc_insert_nav_menu ($position){
$poswanted = 'above';
$nav_code = 
    '<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( \'Menu\', \'twentytwelve\' ); ?></h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( \'Skip to content\', \'twentytwelve\' ); ?>"><?php _e( \'Skip to content\', \'twentytwelve\' ); ?></a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( \'theme_location\' => \'primary\', \'menu_class\' => \'nav-menu\' ) ); ?>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->'

if($position == $poswanted)
    return $nav_code;
}
?>
```

Reading through many questions here leads me to believe that nowdoc and heredoc are not good choices.  I have tried single quotes and escaping the single quotes inside.  Same with double quotes.  Both attempts resulted in error messages.

Any help here would be appreciated.

**EDIT***
The following code is what finally worked.

```
<?php
function rfttc_insert_nav_menu ($position){
    $poswanted = 'below';
    if($position == $poswanted){?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php __( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' )?> </h3>
        <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php
        esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' );
        ?>"><?php  _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' );?>"</a>
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) );?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks to TJohnW for pointing me in the right direction:  processing the inline PHP instead of trying to insert it.

Comment: Does [this earlier article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809535/store-html-php-code-into-php-variable) help?

Comment: Floris:  I am not sure how 'htmlentities()' helps with a constant string.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Can you elaborate on the reasoning, there is most likely another way that makes more sense.

Comment: ATOzTOA:  I want to make it optional where to place the menu (above or below header image).  '$poswanted' will come from a setting once this is working.

Comment: Why not just process it before and then output the navcode ? You don't need php inside of a string of html text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do here. Give this a shot.

```
<?php
function rfttc_insert_nav_menu ($position){
   $poswanted = 'above';
   $nav_code = 
  '<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
   <h3 class="menu-toggle">'. _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</h3>
   <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="' . esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ) . '">' . _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</a>' . wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ) . '</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->';

  if($position == $poswanted) return $nav_code;
}
?>
```

Comment: The above code gives me the following error:  'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /homepages/.../wp-content/themes/.../functions.php on line 6'

Comment: There I fixed it. try it now.

Comment: That's closer than I have gotten this far.  The output is a bit mangled.  I think I see why.

Comment: Good, could I get an answer check :P